# Silverstripe Form Renderwith doesn't show form or any styling

Tags: php, silverstripe

I am trying to render a form with template with the following:

```
function FacebookForm($fbFields) {

        $actions = new FieldSet(
            new FormAction('doFaceBookForm', 'Register')
        );

        $memberfields = singleton('XEUser')->getMemberFormFields();

        $fields = new FieldSet();
        $reqFields = array();
        foreach($fbFields as $key => $value){
            switch($value){
                case 'Gender':
                    $fields->push($memberfields->fieldByName('Gender'));
                    $reqFields[] = 'Gender';
                    break;
                case 'DateOfBirth':
                    $fields->push($memberfields->fieldByName('DateOfBirth'));
                    $reqFields[] = 'DateOfBirth';
                    break;
            }
        }
        $validator = new RequiredFields($reqFields);

        $form = new Form($this, 'FaceBookForm', $fields, $actions,$validator);
        $form->disableSecurityToken();

        return $form->renderWith(array('FacebookController','Page'));
        //return $form;

    }
```

When I just `return $form` my form appears but in the default contentController.ss so I created a new template and added `return $form->renderWith(array('FacebookController','Page'));`. When I do this, I get everything that should be in the page but with no styles being applied at all and the form doesn't even appear. Here is my FacebookController template:

```
<div id="left">

    <h2>Thankyou for signing up with your Facebook account</h2>
    <p>The following details could not be obtained from your Facebook account, please enter them now.</p>
    $form
</div>

<div id="right">

</div>
```

can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: What's actually on the result page? Just the template from ``FacebookController.ss``?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the name of the method in your template:

`$FacebookForm`

Alternatively, you could subclass the Form class and use a custom `forTemplate()` method. More info below.

See:

- http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/forms
- http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/tutorials/3-forms